# How to redirect page into another page and execute code on the redirected page in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having problem with my HOME PAGE when clicking Banana from menu  it will redirect to my PRODUCT PAGE. Home page to Product page redirecting is fine, what I wanted is after it redirected to the Product page, it will execute my code in jquery and show only what was clicked from home page. By default my Product page displays all the items.

Home Page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <title>Home Page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark'>
          <div class='navbar-brand'>
            Fruits
          </div>
          <ul class='navbar-nav'>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <button id='hpbanana' class='btn nav-link'>Banana</button>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <button id='hpblueberry' class='btn nav-link'>Blueberry</button>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <button id='hpbaybas' class='btn nav-link'>Bayabas</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src='js/myjquery.js'></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Product Page:

```
    <head>
      <title>Product Page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class='container'>
        <h3>
          <a href='index.html'>Fruits</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="list-group">
          <ul class='navbar-nav'>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <button id='ppbanana' class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Banana Image</button>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <button id='ppblueberry' class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Blueberry Image</button>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
              <button id='ppbayabas' class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Bayabas Image</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src='js/myjquery.js'></script>
    </body>

    </html>



         .hide {
             display: none;
            }



                  $(document).ready(() => {
                     $('#hpbanana').on('click', () => {
                        window.location.replace("product.html");
                        cyPageNum = 1;
                        if (cyPageNum==1){
                        alert('Banana');//for debugging
                       $('#ppblueberry').addClass('hide');
                       $('#ppbayabas').addClass('hide');
                        }
                      });
                     });
```

Comment: Did you put this JS code in product page?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Home page and Product page inside BODY TAG and before /BODY I inserted <script src='js/myjquery.js'></script>.  I mean myjquery.js is an external file. I used debugging "alert" in jquery to alert me and to know if it function. when pressing banana it alert me before it redirect to product page and that alert is inside the condition if(cyPageNum==1) together with $('#ppblueberry').addClass('hide');  $('#ppbayabas').addClass('hide'); I added class hide.

Comment: JS codes are running only int he current page. You can not hide the element in the target page in previous page. The standard way to do that is to pass a **querystring** in the target URL. Then get the querystring in target page and run a new script to hide that element. For example you shoud do `window.location.replace("product.html?q=banana")` and then get the `q` in target page

Comment: Thanks Ali Sheikhpour, I will try this after office :) and let you know if it work for me. Thanks again :)